# UnknownHostException is not recognized in catch block

Tags: java, exception

One of the method in my code throws `UnknownHostException` exception

I first had a `catch` block like this:

```
catch (Exception e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  System.out.println("Custom Message "+e.getMessage());
  if(e instanceof java.net.UnknownHostException){
      System.out.println("Unknown Host Ex");
  }else{
      System.out.println("OTHER ERROR");
  }
}
```

I am facing a problem where that `if` condition never evaluates to true and hence I am not able to output that there is some host error.

You can see I have a `sysout` just before that which prints this :

```
Custom Message ; nested exception is: 
    java.net.UnknownHostException: abc.xyz
```

After that I wrote a seperate catch block to handle `UnknownHostException` but still is it not getting catched.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, apparently your `UnknownHostException` in wrapped in some other exception. In other words some code above catches `UnknownHostException` and throws:

```
throw new SomeOtherException("Custom Message", unknownHostEx);
```

Print `e.getClass()` to see what kind of exception is wrapping it. You can also try:

```
if(e.getCause() != null && e.getCause() instanceof UnknownHostException)
```

but it's ugly.

BTW you should avoid using `instanceof` and let `catch` figure out the exception itself (but it won't help in your case):

```
catch (java.net.UnknownHostException e) {
      System.out.println("Unknown Host Ex");
}
catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("OTHER ERROR");
}
```

Comment: yeah it works I checked the class and is was something other than `UnknownHostException`, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

`UnknownHostException` is nested inside another `Exception` so it may not be an instance of it but it just contains it. You may eventually check `e.getCause()`